# Filter ArrayList according to a criteria

Tags: java

I have a requirement to write a method that filters an ArrayList between a minimum and maximum range.So the method accepts a List,int min and an integer max.
Here is the method I wrote.

```
public static List<Integer> filterRange(final List<Integer> l3,int min,int max)
{
    System.out.println(l3);
    Iterator<Integer> iter = l3.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        int i=iter.next();
        if (i<=max && i>=min) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(l3);
    return l3;

}
```

However, this would not do the desired function. A suggestion on this would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to get each element and then test it. Currently you're calling `next()` twice in a row. So if you have a List that contains (1,2,3,4) and you're starting the first iteration, this line:

```
if (iter.next().intValue()<=6 && iter.next().intValue()>=2)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (1<=6 && 2>=2)
```

To avoid that store the element and then perform your tests.

```
 while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Integer i = iter.next();
        if (i.intValue()<=6 && i.intValue()>=2) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```

Note that you are not using your `min` and `max` parameters values. Also I don't know why you made your method generic.

---

After your edit, far away from the original post, the problem is that you call `next()` without knowing if your list contains some elements and even if it has, it would loop infinitely since you're not calling `next()` inside your loop (because `hasNext()` will always return `true`). So it should be:

```
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
        int i=iter.next();
        if (i<=6 && i>=2) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```

Be aware that your list can contains `null` elements, so this line `int i=iter.next();` could throw a NPE when trying to unbox the value in the `Integer` object.

Finally if you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) (again be aware of `null` elements) you could do:

```
l.removeIf(i -> i >= min && i <= max);
```

Comment: @Arjit Yes it will be automatically unboxed. I just copy pasted the OP's code (before he edits it to something far away from the original post).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more generic version of the filterRange function. It takes as params:

- a list of comparable objects `List<T>` where `<T extends Comparable<T>>`
- a high value object T
- a low value object T

It returns the same list but with any objects outside of the min/max range removed.

The function iterates through the list of T's and uses the Comparable interface method `compareTo()` to compare each T in the list to the high and low values. If the item falls in range, it add the item to the new list.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> filterRange(List<T> list, T low, T high){
    List<T> newlist = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(T t:list) {
        if(t.compareTo(low)>=0 && t.compareTo(high)<=0) {
            newlist.add(t);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

I tested it with this code

```
String[] array = new String[]{"apple", "banana", "cherry", 
                              "grape", "kiwi", "lemon", 
                              "lime", "orange", "pear", 
                              "plum", "strawberry"};
  List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(array);
  List<String> array1 = filterRange(strings,"c","h");
```

and got:

```
cherry
grape
```

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat -- the post originally specified a generic function, so I tossed this out in a hurry, but it had some issues.  I cleaned it up a bit and actually tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `next()` function twice like that. It gets next element each time. Try storing return from `next()` in a local variable before comparing to `min / max`.

Comment: thanks,i have modified the code. It works fine now :)